# Is Leray's theorem on commutative Hopf algebras proven in Milnor-Moore?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, hopf-algebras, algebraic-combinatorics, combinatorial-hopf-algebras

> **Question 1.** Is a correct proof of Leray's theorem (the one that says that
>   a connected graded Hopf algebra $H$ over a field of characteristic $0$ is
>   isomorphic as an algebra to the symmetric algebra $\operatorname*{Sym}\left(
> H^{+}/\left(  H^{+}\right)  ^{2}\right)  $, where $H^{+}=\operatorname*{Ker}
> \epsilon$ is the kernel of the counit $\epsilon$ of $H$) contained in
>   any version of the famous article "On the structure of Hopf algebras" by
>   Milnor and Moore?
>
> **Question 2.** What are the currently existing sources for Leray's theorem?

---

**Detailed version.** One of the earliest, and still most influential, papers
on Hopf algebras is the article "On the structure of Hopf algebras" by Milnor
and Moore. It exists in two versions:

[A] [John W. Milnor, John C. Moore, *On the structure of Hopf algebras
(preprint)*, reprinted in Milnor's Collected Papers](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=CCB13231812534818220BEF2F01F13F1).

[B] [John W. Milnor, John C. Moore, *On the structure of Hopf algebras*, The
Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 81, No. 2 (Mar., 1965), pp. 211--264](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT9580/v12/undervisningsmateriale/milnor-moore-ann-math-1965.pdf).

I am interested in the following theorem, which I shall call *Leray's theorem*
despite being utterly confused about its provenance (possibly Hopf, Samelson
and Borel have some claims here as well -- any help with the history?):

> **Leray's theorem.** Let $\mathbf{k}$ be a commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra.
>   Let $H$ be a graded Hopf algebra over $\mathbf{k}$ (in the modern meaning of
>   this word -- i.e., it has to have an associative multiplication $m$, a unit
>   $u$, a coassociative comultiplication $\Delta$, a counit $\epsilon$, and an
>   antipode $S$; and all these maps are graded). Assume that $H$ is connected
>   (i.e., the $0$-th graded component of $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{k}$) and
>   commutative (i.e., all $a,b\in H$ satisfy $ab=ba$). Let $H^{+}
> =\operatorname*{Ker}\epsilon$ be the kernel of the counit $\epsilon
> :H\rightarrow\mathbf{k}$ of $H$. Then, $H\cong\operatorname*{Sym}\left(
> H^{+}/\left(  H^{+}\right)  ^{2}\right)  $ as graded $\mathbf{k}$-algebras.

From what I understand, Milnor and Moore claim to prove this theorem in the
particular case when $\mathbf{k}$ is a field. Specifically, it appears to
follow from Theorem 4.6 in [A] and from Theorem 7.5 in [B].

(Notice that the notations in [A] are different from mine. In particular,
associativity and coassociativity are not required by default from Hopf
algebras, but rather required only when explicitly stated. If they wouldn't
require $\mathbf{k}$ to be a field, their results would hence be more general
than what I call Leray's theorem. Also notice that they are using the
notations $I\left(  H\right)  $ for $H^{+}$, as well as $Q\left(  H\right)  $
for $\mathbf{k}\otimes_{H}H^{+}\cong H^{+}/\left(  H^{+}\right)  ^{2}$, and
finally $A\left(  V\right)  $ for the symmetric algebra $\operatorname*{Sym}
V$, at least when we are working with evenly graded algebras.)

What I don't understand is how they prove all this. Their proof relies on a
lemma (Lemma 4.3 in [A], resp. Proposition 4.17 in [B]), which states (at
least in the particular case we care about) that in the situation of Leray's
theorem, if we further assume that $\mathbf{k}$ is a field, the natural
morphism $\left\{  \text{primitive elements of }H\right\}  \rightarrow
H^{+}/\left(  H^{+}\right)  ^{2}$ (which is well-defined since primitive
elements of $H$ always lie in $H^{+}$) is a monomorphism. In other words, the
only primitive element in $\left(  H^{+}\right)  ^{2}$ is $0$. The proof of
this lemma relies on some argument where $H$ is assumed to be finitely
generated, and then an induction is done on the number of generators,
presenting $H$ as a some-sort-of-extension of a Hopf subalgebra $A^{\prime}$
with one less generator by a quotient-of-sorts $A^{\prime\prime}$ with one
generator. ("Generator" always mean algebra generator.) This looks highly
suspicious to me, since I don't think that Hopf algebras can be deconstructed
in such a simple way. I also have never seen arguments like this ever after
Milnor's and Moore's work. Thus, the first question: Is it correct?

I am currently writing up my own proof of Leray's theorem, which uses the
Eulerian idempotent and is probably common knowledge in the Hopf-combinatorics
crowd. Thus, the second question: What should I be referencing?

Comment: Re "I don't think that Hopf algebras can be deconstructed in such a simple way". They are dealing with graded connected Hopf algebras, and that extra hypothesis gives you all sorts of advantages. What part of their proof (in [B], which is all I have access to) are you concerned about?

Comment: In the proof of Proposition 4.17 in [B], they define $A'$ to be the subalgebra of $A$ (which is my $H$) generated by $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m$ (which are all but one of the generators of $A$ lifted from a homogeneous basis of $Q\left(A\right) = A^+ / \left(A^+\right)^2$). Why is $A'$ a coalgebra? Or do they not use this at all? They seem to apply the induction hypothesis to $A'$ instead of $A$, which seems to require it to be a coalgebra.

Comment: Oh. It's not just "all but one of the generators", but actually "all but one of the highest-degree generators". And now I see why the comultiplication restricts to a map $A' \to A' \otimes A'$ ! I'm going to check in more detail, but it definitely makes more sense now.

Comment: Precisely, the degrees of the chosen generators are crucial.

Comment: For you "graded" means graded in positive integers?

Comment: @YCor: Nonnegative integers, to be precise.

Comment: I think "graded" means graded by the integers, and then "connected" means graded in the nonnegative integers with degree 0 component equal to $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to give this question some closure. Basically, it was answered by @JohnPalmieri in his comment; let me just expand this answer.

The proof of Proposition 4.17 in the Milnor/Moore paper [B] is correct (at least the part that I was having troubles with). The argument is rather surprising and seriously uses the assumption that the base field is a field! Here are the main ideas (of the proof of Proposition 4.17, not of the proof of Leray's theorem):

- We want to prove that if $A$ is a commutative connected graded Hopf algebra over a field $K$ of characteristic $0$, then the natural morphism $P\left(A\right) \to Q\left(A\right)$ (where, we recall, $P\left(A\right)$ denotes the primitive elements of $A$, whereas $Q\left(A\right) = \left(\ker \varepsilon\right) / \left(\ker \varepsilon\right)^2$) is injective. (This is not the whole statement of Proposition 4.17, but the only part I care about here.)
- We can show that $A$ is a direct limit of Hopf subalgebras that are finitely generated as $K$-algebras. (This is the first place where we use that $K$ is a field.) So we WLOG assume that $A$ is finitely generated as a $K$-algebra (by abstract nonsense).
- Thus, $A = K\left[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{m+1}\right]$ for some homogeneous elements $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{m+1}$ of $A$ having positive degree. Assume WLOG that $x_{m+1}$ has the highest degree among these elements $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{m+1}$.
- Now, the $K$-subalgebra $A' := K\left[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m\right]$ of $A$ is a Hopf subalgebra. To see this, notice that the coproducts $\Delta x_i$ for $i \leq m$ all belong to $A' \otimes A'$ (because $\Delta x_i - x_i \otimes 1 - 1 \otimes x_i$ is a sum of tensors whose tensor factors have smaller degree than $x_i$, which entails that these factors cannot use $x_{m+1}$ because any appearance of $x_{m+1}$ would raise their degree higher than it can go).
- Now, the ideal of $A$ generated by all $a' - \varepsilon\left(a'\right)$ for $a' \in A'$ is a Hopf ideal of $A$, and therefore the quotient $A''$ of $A$ by this ideal is also a commutative Hopf algebra, with only one generator (the projection of $x_{m+1}$).
- By induction over the number of generators, we can assume that the proposition is already proven for $A'$ instead of $A$ (since $A'$ needs only $m$ generators $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m$). Also, it is easy to show that the proposition holds for $A''$ instead of $A$ (as $A''$ has only one generator). Splicing this together via an exact-sequence argument yields the proposition for $A$.

I have not gone through the details, but this looks like a nice argument which I haven't seen elsewhere.

Meanwhile, I prove different versions of Leray's theorem in different ways (based on ideas by Patras, Loday, etc.):

- If $K$ is any commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra (not necessarily a field!), and if $A$ is a commutative connected graded $K$-Hopf algebra, then $A \cong \operatorname{Sym}\left(Q\left(A\right)\right)$ as algebras (where $Q\left(A\right) = \left(\ker \varepsilon\right) / \left(\ker \varepsilon\right)^2$ as before). This is (currently) Theorem 1.7.29 (e) in [Darij Grinberg and Victor Reiner, *Hopf algebras in Combinatorics*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/HopfComb-sols.pdf) (this will be on the arXiv soon, once I've added a few more things). Note that this version of Leray's theorem does not require $K$ to be a field, but (unlike Theorem 7.5 in [B]) only provides *one* isomorphism $\operatorname{Sym}\left(Q\left(A\right)\right) \to A$, whereas Theorem 7.5 in [B] gives an infinite family thereof. Roughly speaking, the isomorphism it provides comes from an "exponential of the Eulerian idempotent". Note also that (unlike Milnor and Moore) I only consider evenly graded algebras (i.e., no superalgebras), and I require coassociativity.
- In Theorem 40.13 of [*On the logarithm of the identity on
  connected filtered bialgebras*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/logid.pdf), I replicate the whole infinite family of isomorphisms from Theorem 7.5 of [B] (though still only for evenly graded algebras with coassociativity). The proof is a long and painful mess (although it doesn't help that I haven't tried much to streamline it, but written it up as it evolved). It seems that the generality of $K$ not being a field is cutting off many useful shortcuts here; the fieldness of $K$ is used in [B] many times (apart from the uses mentioned above, I think it is used in making $E^0\left(A\right)$ a Hopf algebra).

Note that I am still a bit skeptical about whether Theorem 7.5 in [B] really does not require the associativity and the coassociativity of $A$. I do not care much about this, but somehow it strikes me as more of a miracle than I would have expected -- then again, the Milnor/Moore paper has its share of miracles...